# BMI caculator want to have a parseInt() function

Tags: javascript

i just got the code below and i found that i need to do the  parseInt() function..That means i need use this function to find a integer answer for my BMI answer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> 
        Calculate your BMI
    </title>


<script type=text/javascript>
function CalculateBmi(){
var weight= document.getElementsByName('weight')[0].value;
var height= document.getElementsByName('height')[0].value;

if(weight>0 && height>0){
var finalBMI=(weight/(height*height))*703;
document.getElementsByName('BMI')[0].value=finalBMI;
}
}
</script>
</head>


<body>
    <form name="Form">
    weight in pounds
    <input type="text"  name="weight" />
        <br/>
    height in inches
    <input type="text" name="height"/>
        <br/>
    <input type="button" value="calculate BMI" onclick="CalculateBmi()">
        <br />
    BMI result
    <input type="text" name="BMI"/>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

The code above is what i did, i have try to put () in the co such as

document.getElementsByName('BMI')[0].value=ParseInt(finalBMI);

but i am sure i miss something.

Comment: Next time **show what you tried** instead of saying you tried, but show no effort of it in the code. "I tried to X and Y, but nothing worked". We can't tell you **what** you did wrong if you don't show us how you used it wrong.

Comment: i am sorry man, i posted something i have try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var weight= parseInt(document.getElementsByName('weight')[0].value, 10);
var height= parseInt(document.getElementsByName('height')[0].value, 10);
```

Next time, please show us your attempts **in the question**!

Comment: @user2791881 Please accept my answer if it fulfills your question (click the check mark left to my answer).

Comment: i hope i can , but i put these in and it seems nothing happened